# Give an example to show that there need not exist $x\in X$ such that $\|x\|=1$ and $Lx=1$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed linear space and suppose $L$ is a bounded linear functional on $X$ such that $\|L\|=1$. Given $\epsilon>0$ show there exists $x_0\in X$ such that $\|x_0\|=1$ and $Lx_0>1-\epsilon$. Give an example to show that there need not exist $x\in X$ such that $\|x\|=1$ and $Lx=1$.

My Work:

I proved the first part but failed to find an example. Everytime I found examples such that no $x$ exists so that $\|x\|=1$ and $Lx=1$, I could not show the condition $\|L\|=1$. Can anybody please give me a hint?

Answer (score 3):

Consider $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ with the taxicab norm, with the standard basis $e_i$ for $i=1$ to $\infty$.  Define $L(e_i)=(1-1/i)$.

Comment: But I don't see that $L(e_i)$ is a scalar... Isn't $L(e_i)=(1-1/i)$ the correct one?

Comment: And do you mean $(0,0,...,0,1,0,...)$ (where $i$th coordinate is $1$ and all others $0$) by $e_i$? Then does it span all of $R^\infty$? Or subspace of $R^\infty$?

Comment: Sorry, I did not read "functional" carefully, you are correct that this is not a functional; it is an operator on $\mathbb{R}^\infty$.  Unfortunately I am kind of busy right now but you could try to check if the example still works if we define $L$ the way you suggested.  If not we could use the box norm instead and it should work.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant by $e_i$.  It spans by definition of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the answer.

Comment: Note that, in T.A.E's example, $X$ is a Banach space.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=L^{1}[0,1]$, and define the linear function $\Phi(f)=\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx$. Then
$$
         |\Phi(f)| \le \int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|xdx \le \int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|dx = \|f\|.
$$
Therefore $\|\Phi\| \le 1$. Let $f_{\epsilon}=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\chi_{[1-\epsilon,1]}$. Then $\|f_{\epsilon}\|=1$ and
$$
    \Phi\left(f_{\epsilon}\right)= \frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{1-\epsilon}^{1}xdx
         = \frac{1}{2\epsilon}(1-(1-\epsilon)^{2})=1-\frac{\epsilon}{2}.
$$
Hence, $\|\Phi\|=1$. If $\Phi(f)=1=\|f\|$, then
$$
         \int_{0}^{1}(x-1)|f(x)|dx \ge \int_{0}^{1}(xf(x)-|f(x)|)dx
           = \Phi(f)-\|f\| = 0.
$$
Therefore $(x-1)|f(x)|=0$ a.e.., which is a contradiction.

Comment: I think the O.P. wanted $L$ to be a bounded linear functional, not just a bounded linear map.

Comment: @MikeF : Thanks for that note. I missed that. I think the argument still works the functional that I've now posted instead, unless I've made a new mistake. :)

Comment: Looks good to me! +1.